Does "un torseur" denote the same thing as a torsor?
I am working with a mechanical engineer from France who wants to measure (in English) the "Torsor of mechanical actions" would this refer to a Tensor or Vector of acceleration and rotation, or a specific mechanical property like momentum or moment?
Any general recommendations for resources for translating French for engineers would be very helpful as well.

We have vecteur, tenseur, torseur. Torseur is more specialized. The context would be needed, "mechanical actions" is a bit vague.

We are generally want to measure the issues (eg stress, strain, shock at different acceleration and rotation) a wheel may encounter as it rotates. I cannot really be more specific than that

He's probably referencing this https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torseur_des_actions_m%C3%A9caniques

French torseur translates to a screw, as in Screw theory, not to a torsor. The torseur des actions mécaniques is new to me; I'll wager it is the wrench of the contact forces applied to the rigid body of interest, i. e. the total wrench minus the gravitational-inertial terms. Looks like your French colleague could spend some time training in English.
